# Can't I fill a LinkedHashMap in a Java List?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm learning spring boot.
I wrote the following code using groovy:

```
def result = [:]
def bannerList = [
      ['img_url': 'asdf', 'link_url': 'qwert',],
      ['img_url': 'asdf', 'link_url': 'qwert'],
]
result.put("banner", bannerList)
return result
```

but I got an error, here is the message:

```
"message": "Cannot cast object '{banner=[{img_url=asdf, link_url=qwert}, {img_url=asdf, link_url=qwert}]}' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to class 'java.util.List' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.List(LinkedHashMap)",
```

But when I return bannerlist directly, it is successful.
I thought that the LinkedHashMap could not be filled in the List, but the variable "result" in the debug mode can be correctly assigned, but it can't be returned as a result.

Comment: Not a groovy guy, but to get the list of entries in a Map, you have to go through Map.entrySet() (or Map.values(), or map.keySet())

Comment: One of your objects is a Map, the other is a List. No, you can't use one for the other.

Comment: Well, `result` is key-value, so it is certainly not a list as the error also points out (hint: `"Cannot cast object '{banner` - objects starting with curly braces aren't arrays nor lists: they are maps). You need to wrap it into a list.

Comment: Hello, this seems to be a higher level issue. The result map is created and is able to be printed in the message. Is there any other code we can look at such as the method this is in. Is this code executed in a controller class? I executed this code in https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and it appears to work fine.

Comment: I'm guessing your method's return type is `List`, while the variable you are trying to return is of type `LinkedHashMap`. Replace `List` return type with a `Map` and you should be ready to go. Or wrap `result` with a list if you want to keep `List` return type, e.g. `return [result]` - it will return a list containing a map and it should satisfy your return type expectation.

Comment: @BackSlash Hi~ Thank you for your comment. I solved this problem according to your prompt, I changed two places: 1. def result = [] 2.result << ["banner": bannerList]

Answer (score 0):

According to the @BackSlash prompt in the comments, I changed the code and solved this error:

```
        def result = []
        def bannerList = [
                ['img_url': 'asdf', 'link_url': 'qwert',],
                ['img_url': 'asdf', 'link_url': 'qwert',]
        ]
        result << ["banner": bannerList]
        return result
```

Thanks for the help of friends in the comment area.